# Ambiguity in a ellipse integral

Tags: integration, parametrization, line-integrals

Suppose we have a ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 1$, and we want to integrate a density $f(x,y) = 3 \cdot |xy| $ over the ellipse.

I was trying to solve this problem in two different ways and i find 2 different answers.

First I called $2y = h$ and then the elipse turns to be a circumference, in this new scale: $x^2 + h^2 = 1$ and my density turns to be $f(x,h) = \frac{3}{2} |xh| $. Then i integrate this density on the parametric circumference $\alpha (t) = ( \cos t , \sin t )$ what leads me to the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{3}{2} |\sin t \cos t| dt = 3.$

Second approach I parameterized the elipse with $\alpha (t) = ( \cos t , 0.5 \sin t ) \implies | \alpha'(t)| = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt(1 + 3 sin^2t)$ and then the integral of $f(x,y)$ over the elipse is : $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{3}{2} |\sin t \cos t| \frac{1}{2} \sqrt(1 + 3 sin^2t) dt = 7/3$ .

What approach is wrong? and what am i misunderstanding? I was suppose to think that this integral does not depend on the coordinate system.

Comment: When you computed the density $\frac32|xh|$, you were treating it as a density with respect to area (since your coordinate transformation $y=2h$ doubles areas). That would be correct if you were integrating with respect to area, over the whole interior of the ellipse. But then you integrated with respect to arc length, over the perimeter of the ellipse, which is something quite different. You'd have to wok with density with respect to arc length, and your transformation $y=2h$ affects that in a more complicated way than just a factor $2$.

Comment: Thanks, how can i find the actual new density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I will try to sketch what is happening with your change of coordinates so you can see the problem.

Let $A := \mathbb{R}^2\;$ be the first plane in consideration and $e:[0,1) \longrightarrow A\;$ an ellipse in that plane. Now, consider a second plane $B:= \mathbb{R}^2\;$ and a circumference $c:[0,1) \longrightarrow B\;$ in this second plane. Your change of coordinates consists in a $C^1$ invertible map $h: A \rightarrow B$ (where $h^{-1}$ is also $C^1$) such that $h \circ e = c\;$. You can click here to see: [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuU0P.png).

Now, consider the initial density map $f: A \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We get that the correspondent density map in $B\;$, namely $g: B \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\;$, is actually as you have said, it is $g = f \circ h^{-1}$. So, where is the problem? Let us start by what you want to calculate and see if it reaches what you actually calculated.

$\displaystyle \int_e f \cdot ds = \int_0^1 f(e(t))\ |e'(t)|\ dt = \int_0^1 f\circ h^{-1}(c(t))\ |(h^{-1}\circ c)'(t)|\ dt = \int_0^1 g(c(t))\ |D_{c(t)}h^{-1} \cdot c'(t)|\ dt$

If we recall what you actually calculated in part 1, it was $\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(c(t))\ | c'(t)|\ dt \;$. So we can see that it was missing to take account for the action of the derivative of $h^{-1}\;$ in the velocity of the curve $c\;$.

Finally, in part 2 this problem did not appear because you computed $(h^{-1}\circ c)' \;$ directly.